# sending an SMTP email using jinja2

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, smtplib, email-templates

I am trying to send an email with an html template using smtplib and jinja2. I have this code to send the email

```
import smtplib

from email.message import EmailMessage
msg = EmailMessage()

msg["Subject"] = "SUBJECT"
msg["From"] = "emailaddress@gmail.com"
msg["To"] = "recipient@email.com"
msg.set_content("""
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <title>email_template</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p> {{CONTENT}} </p>
    </body>
    """, subtype="html")

with smtplib.SMTP_SSL("smtp.gmail.com", 465) as smtp:
    #logs in to the email server
    smtp.login("emailaddress@gmail.com", "password")
    smtp.send_message(msg)
```

I have this code in a separate file which enters strings into a template using jinja

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')

def email_template():
    return render_template("email_template.html", content=contentPY)

contentPY="This is the string that will be inserted into the html template"
```

My objective is to insert data into the html template, and then send it out as an email. Basically, I am trying to combine these two snippets of code, but I am new to python so I am stuck.

Answer (score -1):

`render_template()` or `render_template_string()` requires an application context, so you must call it from a view function or a function called by the view function.

So, in your case, you can create a helper function to send emails:

```py
# utils.py

import smtplib
from email.message import EmailMessage

from flask import render_template

def send_email(subject, recipient, content):
    msg = EmailMessage()
    msg["Subject"] = subject
    msg["From"] = "emailaddress@gmail.com"
    msg["To"] = recipient
    msg.set_content(
        render_template("email_template.html", content=content),
        subtype="html"
    )

    with smtplib.SMTP_SSL("smtp.gmail.com", port=465) as smtp:
        smtp.login("emailaddress@gmail.com", "password")
        smtp.send_message(msg)
```

And then call it from your app:

```py
# app.py

from flask import Flask
from .utils import send_email

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    # ...
    send_email("SUBJECT", "recipient@gmail.com", "YOUR CONTENT")
    # ...
```